# How to replace deprecated RSA low level OpenSSL 3.0 APIs with equivalent EVP functions?

Tags: c++, c, linux, openssl

This working RSA OpenSSL code

```
void SwapBytes( unsigned char *pv, size_t n )
{
   unsigned char *p = pv;
   size_t lo, hi;
   for ( lo = 0, hi = n - 1; hi > lo; lo++, hi-- )
   {
      char tmp = p[lo];
      p[lo] = p[hi];
      p[hi] = tmp;
   }
}

void RSA(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
        BIGNUM *bnN = NULL;
        BIGNUM *bnE = NULL;

        RSA *keys = RSA_new();

        BN_hex2bn(&bnN, modulus);
        BN_hex2bn(&bnE, public_exp);

        RSA_set0_key(keys, bnN, bnE, NULL);

        int modulus_size = RSA_size(keys);

        SwapBytes(plaintext, modulus_size);
        
        int cipher_len = RSA_public_encrypt(modulus_size, plaintext, ciphertext, keys, RSA_NO_PADDING);

        RSA_free(keys);

        SwapBytes(ciphertext, modulus_size);
}
```

when compiled produces deprecated warnings such as

```
/mnt/c/Projects/src/rsa.cpp:37:102: warning: ‘int RSA_public_encrypt(int, const unsigned char*, unsigned char*, RSA*, int)’ is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   37 |         int cipher_len = RSA_public_encrypt(modulus_size, plaintext, ciphertext, keys, RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

which can be suppressed using this compiler option

> -Wno-deprecated-declarations

However, the OpenSSL dev team notes:

> ```
> Use of the low level APIs has been informally discouraged by the OpenSSL dev team for a long time.
> However in OpenSSL 3.0 this is made more formal. All such low level APIs have been deprecated.
> You may still use them in your applications, but you may start to see deprecation warnings
> during compilation (dependent on compiler support for this).
> Deprecated APIs may be removed from future versions of OpenSSL so you are strongly encouraged
> to update your code to use the high level APIs instead.
> ```

**Question**

It's suggested to replace the above low level API's with [EVP](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP).
Is there an RSA example to replace the above code with OpenSSL EVP functions?

Comment: Are you writing in c or c++? It's usually a mistake to use both tags.

Comment: Welcome to my world. I maintain code that uses OpenSSL and every few years OpenSSL decides to deprecrate or make a backwards-incompatible API change, and one needs to start digging through its source, and make copious Google searches, to figure out WTF to do about it. Perhaps this is a good excuse to bite the bullet and rewrite everything using GnuTLS, which remained stable for as long as I can remember, and its API is much more C++-friendly. My code can use both OpenSSL or GnuTLS, and it's one painfull API break from ditching OpenSSL altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no openssl expert, but going through the hard to read DOC's I figured out the below conversation which from my testing generates the same output as as your function (assuming no SwapBytes is called as you don't provide that).

It can be broken down into three parts I think.

- setting up PARAMS array with the key parameters using [OSSL_PARAM_BLD_xx](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/OSSL_PARAM_BLD.html) functions
- creating the RSA key from the PARAMS array using using [EVP_PKEY_fromdata](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_fromdata.html) function
- encrypting the data using [EVP_PKEY_xxx](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_encrypt.html) functions

Sample:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/param_build.h>

template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_handle(T* handle, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{handle, deleter};
}

void newRSA(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned char *ciphertext, int length, char const* modulus, char const* public_exp)
{
    // build BIGNUM values
    BIGNUM* num{ nullptr };
    BN_hex2bn(&num, modulus);
    assert(num != nullptr);
    auto bnN = make_handle(num, BN_free);
    num = nullptr;

    BN_hex2bn(&num, public_exp);
    assert(num != nullptr);
    auto bnE = make_handle(num, BN_free);

    // Build params to create PARAM array
    auto params_build = make_handle(OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new(), OSSL_PARAM_BLD_free);
    assert(params_build.get() != nullptr);

    auto result = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(params_build.get(), "n", bnN.get());
    assert(result == 1);
    result = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(params_build.get(), "e", bnE.get());
    assert(result == 1);
    result = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(params_build.get(), "d", nullptr);
    assert(result == 1);

    // create PARAMS array
    auto params = make_handle(OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(params_build.get()), OSSL_PARAM_free);

    // cleanup params build up
    params_build.reset();
    bnN.reset();
    bnE.reset();

    // Create RSA key from params
    auto ctx = make_handle(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(nullptr, "RSA", nullptr), EVP_PKEY_CTX_free);
    assert(ctx.get() != nullptr);

    result = EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(ctx.get());
    assert(result == 1);

    EVP_PKEY *key = nullptr;
    result = EVP_PKEY_fromdata(ctx.get(), &key, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params.get());
    assert(result == 1);

    auto keys = make_handle(key, EVP_PKEY_free);

    // cleanup params
    params.reset();


    // RSA_size equivalent
    int modulus_size = (EVP_PKEY_get_bits(keys.get()) + 7) / 8;
    assert(length == modulus_size);


    // setup encryption from the key generated above
    auto enc_ctx = make_handle(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(keys.get(), nullptr), EVP_PKEY_CTX_free);
    assert(enc_ctx.get() != nullptr);

    result = EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(enc_ctx.get());
    assert(result == 1);

    // encrypt using RSA_NO_PADDING
    result = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(enc_ctx.get(), RSA_NO_PADDING);
    assert(result == 1);

    // encrypt
    size_t outlen = length;
    result = EVP_PKEY_encrypt(enc_ctx.get(), ciphertext, &outlen, plaintext, length);
    assert(result == 1);

    assert(outlen == length);
}
```

Comment: Tested and works great! No need to use the option -Wno-deprecated-declarations now. Thanks for the code!

Comment: I'm having a weird issue, deprecated code in the question works fine, but using this answer code, `EVP_PKEY_encrypt` result is -1

Comment: You can call ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) to the last error string.  My guess is that one of the steps to setup the enc_ctx failed.  You need to go trough each step and make sure each step works correctly.